# Filtering data using string YYYYMMDD date in query

Tags: sql, criteria

Below `WHERE` clause is used to filter the data using `BETWEEN` keyword.

```
WHERE dateCol BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

But the table contains column of data type `CHARACTER` which stores date like `20130407` (YYYYMMDD). I can't change the data type of the column because of privilege and it is already present and in use. Now I need to filter the data between two dates like between `20130701` and `20130801`. I can't use `BETWEEN` because that column is not of `DATE` type. Might be usage of `IN` criteria is alternative, but it makes query very lengthy and not dynamic. Can someone please suggest how to do filter this between two dates?

Comment: is this ms sql or mysql?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the same format for the comparisons:

```
WHERE dateCol BETWEEN '20130701' and '20130801'
```

I do suspect, however, that you really mean:

```
WHERE dateCol >= '20130701' and
      dateCol < '20130801'
```

To get everything in July without the first of August.